# Flutter: I want to create a global variant. After close the app, it can be saved for the next time I open the app again

Tags: flutter, global-variables

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Global {
  static SharedPreferences _prefs;
  static String key;

  static Future init() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var _key = _prefs.getString("key");
    if (_key != null) {
      key = _key;
    }
  }

  static saveKey(value) => _prefs.setString("key", value);

}
```

Here I create a global class. And I set and get value by this way.

```
Global.key = value; //set
Global.key; //get
```

But after I close the app, the value is gone. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

   class Global {
      static SharedPreferences _prefs;
      static String key;
      String get init => key;  // adding a getter
      static Future init() async {
          WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
         _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          var _key = _prefs.getString("key");
          if (_key != null) {
          key = _key;
       }
      }

       static saveKey(value) => _prefs.setString("key", value);

  }


    Global().init =value; or  Global.init = value; //set
    Global().init; //get  Global.init; //get
```

Comment: I follow your way. But it said "There isn’t a setter named 'init' in class 'Global'.
Try correcting the name to reference an existing setter, or declare the setter."

Answer (score 0):

Are you ever calling your `Init` function in your Main method?

```
void main() async {
  await Global.init();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Assuming you're doing that, the other mistake here is how you're trying to store your value. Use the `saveKey` function you have in place that's what it's there for. Throw this on one of your pages.

```
ElevatedButton(
 onPressed: () {
 Global.saveKey('Test');
 },
 child: Text('Test'),
),
```

Your `Global` class was perfectly fine, its how you were trying to use it. Try this though, only change is that I included a null check so you don't have to create an extra variable that's not used. Also added a print statement that will print the stored value when you re-start the app. It all works fine on my end.

```
class Global {
  static SharedPreferences _prefs;
  static String key;

  static Future init() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    key = _prefs.getString('key') ?? ''; // null check here

    debugPrint(key);
  }

  static saveKey(value) => _prefs.setString("key", value);
}
```